# Selenium standalone only works with chrome

Tags: selenium, protractor, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm using my protractor tests run with a selenium standalone server.

Now i want to support all browsers. 
I created a folder with the standalone (3.0.1) and a subfolder `driver` with `IEDriver, geckodriver, chromedriver`.

I added the path to the driver folder to the system PATH.

The standalone is running with no args (i do not know what to add).

My Config is:

```
var TIMEOUT = 20000;
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4448/wd/hub',
    baseUrl: 'https://intmachine.project.com/',

    /*
     list the Suites to run locally here
     */
    specs: [
        './UseCases/protractorTestcaseNightly.js',
    ],
    capabilities: [
        {
            'browserName': 'firefox',
            'firefox_binary':'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe'
            // shardTestFiles: false,
            // maxInstances: 1,
            // maxSessions: -1,
            // restartBrowserBetweenTests: true,
        },
    ],

    getPageTimeout: TIMEOUT,
    allScriptsTimeout: TIMEOUT,
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: TIMEOUT,
        isVerbose: true,
        includeStackTrace: true
    },
    framework: "jasmine2",
    //rootElement: 'html',
    onPrepare: function () {
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        browser.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

    }
};
```

Update:
i changed "Capa..." to capabilities and now get:

```
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[launcher] Error: TypeError: Target browser must be a string, but is <undefined>; did you forget to call forBrowser()?
    at TypeError (native)
    at Builder.build (C:\dev\dcps-angular\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\builder.js:417:13)
    at DriverProvider.getNewDriver (C:\dev\dcps-angular\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\driverProvider.js:42:27)
    at Runner.createBrowser (C:\dev\dcps-angular\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:203:37)
    at C:\dev\dcps-angular\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:293:21
    at _fulfilled (C:\dev\dcps-angular\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\dev\dcps-angular\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\dev\dcps-angular\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\dev\dcps-angular\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (C:\dev\dcps-angular\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 100
```

Comment: what error you get?

Comment: Did you set `marionette: true` in your capabilities? What version of Firefox are you using? What version of Protractor are you using?

Comment: Hi @cnishina, i use:
`protractor@4.0.14
selenium-webdriver-standalone@3.0.1
firefox 51.0.1`
**i added `marionette: true` but still get same error**

Comment: At the time Protractor 4.0.14 was released, the recommended solution was to use the selenium standalone server 2.53.1 with Firefox 47. In Protractor release 5 prior to the release of Firefox 51, it was also recommended to use Firefox 47 with marionette capability set to false to use the legacy drive. The combination of Protractor 4.0.14 with Firefox 51 and selenium standalone server 3.0.1 was never tested. My suggestion is to use Protractor 5. Question: what version of gecko driver are you using?

Comment: i use geckodriver 0.14.0 (https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases). Do i have to give the path to my config?